# can a Windows firewall rule detect what adapter is in use?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall

Is there a way for a Windows 10 firewall rule to determine what network adapter is in use? Can it differentiate between Wi-Fi, TAP, Ethernet, etc.?

Poking around Windows Firewall for the first time, I don't see any settings related to network adapter, but I wonder if the "local IP address" settings could be useful. Would the different adapters show up as different IP addresses, in some way that is consistent enough to make a rule out of it?

Answer (score 0):

Like is was said [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), i think it is possible, if Network Discovery is enabled, for mapping and other stuff...

1. Click Start, click Run, and then type firewall.cpl. This opens the Windows Firewall Control Panel applet.
2. Choose Allow a program through Windows Firewall.
3. On the Exceptions tab, select the Network Discovery check box.
4. Click OK to close the firewall applet.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. You pointed me to a page that has nothing to do with detecting an adapter in a firewall rule, but rather appears to be about debugging situations in which firewall rules are blocking your LAN. My question is not specific to a LAN or other network. It's specific to the network adapter. I'm asking about **firewall rules** in particular. I want to **create** such a rule.